# MyBatis mapper does not load query

Tags: mybatis

I have a service which executes a SQL query from a mapper.
Last week was working fine, but today isn't working.
It is on the master branch and all of my colleagues can run it locally with no problems.
Only on my machine isn't loading the results from the query.
I've tried - updating, cloning, opening from their archived folder of the project and still not working.
Any ideas what it could be?

Answer (score 0):

So guys, just FYI Docker sometimes saves its virtual machine's date and it is different than the local one.
Unfortunately on wake up/turn on it is not updated.
Be careful if you are using timestamp with docker!